# Stripe key not set in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, stripe-payments

I am having trouble setting the keys for stripe. I have set up an initializer:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :stripe_publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :stripe_secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]

puts "================"
puts :stripe_secret_key
puts "================"
```

I added the puts to check the value in :stripe_secret_key and this is the output when I start up my local rails server:

```
$ STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_xxxxxx STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_xxxxxx rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
================
stripe_secret_key
================
[2014-06-17 09:31:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-17 09:31:43] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
[2014-06-17 09:31:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=51790 port=3000
```

Instead of the actual key what is being passed to the Stripe API is simply "stripe_secret_key". Any idea what the problem is? I'm sure it's simple, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the ***symbol*** `:stripe_secret_key` with `puts :stripe_secret_key`, so the string `stripe_secret_key` gets printed.

Instead use `puts Rails.configuration.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]` Or `puts Stripe.api_key` to check the set `stripe_secret_key` value.

Comment: Thank you. App still not working, but that was the problem with the puts statement.

Comment: Glad to help :) You can post another question with the details, if you  don't resolve the next issue even after debugging.